# Apache mod_proxy and Node Express renders plain text

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxy, mod-proxy

I am running a webserver with Apache 2.2.12 as default webserver bound to port 80. 
For a new project I need to proxy one of Apaches bound domains via port 80 to a Node Express Server 4.7 which runs on the same machine on port 4000.

The Express process served alone is running fine with expected results.
Means, when I visit my-domain.com:4000 everything looks good.

Ok, so I set up a virtual host in Apache which should proxy my-domain.com to the Express server on port 4000.

I have tried proxying to localhost:4000 or my-domain.com:4000 but Apache is always rendering the Express response as plain text not as real HTML.
This means I see the HTML-String inside my browser instead of the parsed website.
The Browser just echos the Express string inside its own html-wrapper nested in a pre-tag when you explore the source code via inspector.

My Apache-Config looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName my-domain.com
       ProxyRequests Off
       <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
       </Proxy>

      ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/ 
      ProxyPassReverse / http://locahost:4000/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Found the parameter inside apache2.conf

setting:

```
    DefaultType text/plain
```

to

```
    DefaultType text/html
```

worked out.